# Calculating of derivative

Tags: derivatives

I'm a little confused with using derivatives. I understand that derivatives respond to question

> how result of function changes when input of function changes

However I do not understand why we calculate derivative of $f(x) = x^2$ instead of calculating $f(2)$ and $f(2.001)$ and subtracting these two values of $f(2.001)$ from $f(2.0)$

Could someone explain that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, these are almost the same thing. The calculation
$$\frac{f(2.001)-f(2)}{0.001}$$
is an approximation to the *exact* rate of change at $x=2$. Note that the rate of change isn't just $f(2.001)-f(2)$; that's just the change in the value of the function. You need to divide by the amount of change in $x$ to get the *rate* of change; this is often expressed $\Delta y / \Delta x$.

For a much better approximation, you could calculate
$$\frac{f(2.00000001)-f(2)}{0.00000001}$$

Ultimately, the derivative is *defined* to be the limit of such expressions:
$$f'(2) := \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}$$

Finally, note that in addition to being exact (and not just an approximation), it is much simpler to calculate $f'(x)$, since in this example it is just $2x$. That being said, in the "real world", we don't always have nice functions like $x^2$, but rather only numerical data. In that case, you can approximate the derivative as above.